# AIX Continuous Log Monitoring

Tags: logging, monitoring, aix, tail, continuous

I have a simple requirement to keep monitoring a log file and when certain term appears in it, send a JMS message. I have used the code (`checkScript.sh`) below and it works perfect until the midnight when an archiving script kicks in.

```
string="requiredstring"
tail -n 0 -f /home/user/log.log | \
while read LINE
do
echo "$LINE" | grep -q $string
java tibjmsProducer -server tcp://localhost:7222 -user admin -password admin -queue test.queue "$LINE"
done
```

At midnight, there is an archiving script that starts and renames the log.log file to log.log.1 and touches the log.log flie. So we will end up with two files `log.log` and `log.log.1`. As AIX can't monitor these file changes using `tail` as the tail in AIX keeps tracking only the file descriptor, I have written another script which will restart the above code after the archiving is completed.

```
kill -9 `ps -ef|grep "tail -n 0 -f" | grep "checkScript"| awk '{print $2}'`
echo "Killed process. Restarting the shell script"
./checkScript.sh >> /home/user/Service.log 2>&1 &
```

Interestingly, it does work exactly as intended. But post restarting, the log file stops getting monitored and no events get triggered but `ps -ef` on the script shows that the `checkScript` is running doing the tail.

Anything am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of blindly renaming, I suggest you `cp` and then `cat /dev/null` (which will keep the same inode and allow your original process to continue without interruption). Also, I suggest you use the `date` command. Something like

```
#!/bin/sh
DT=`date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
LF="/home/user/log.log"
FN="$LF-$DT"
cp "$LF" "$FN"
cat /dev/null > "$LF"
```

Finally, you might consider adding (assuming you have `bzip2`)

```
bzip2 -9 "$FN"
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Elliott. They are doing exactly the same, copying all the files and then gzip+tar the folder of all the oversized log files. To counter this problem I have written a script to restart my checkScript file and put it in crontab. But interestingly it is not working as expected when run from cron, but works fine when I start manually in the morning (losing 8 hours of transactions)

Comment: @aadi If the last step is `cat /dev/null > $LF` (instead of `rm`) then you don't need to restart your monitor. The file descriptor will remain constant but the existing file contents will be removed.

Comment: Thanks Elliott. The are using `> filename.log` for resetting the file. I think this is equivalent to using what you have suggested. I will check and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Ha! Finally a simple (proper) Google gave the solution to this stupid problem. What I forgot to mention was (thinking it doesn't matter), my script gets restarted by a `crontab`. And the cron is running with a different set of environment variables that doesn't include Java directory. Hence while the script is running, it is not pushing the results to the JMS server.

To fix this issue, I have modified the restart script like below and it worked like a charm!

```
. ${HOME}/.profile
kill -9 `ps -ef|grep "tail -n 0 -f" | grep "checkScript"| awk '{print $2}'`
echo "Killed process. Restarting the shell script"
./checkScript.sh >> /home/user/Service.log 2>&1 &
```

This loaded all the correct and required paths for me and the script is working fine now. The `. ${HOME}/.profile` command helped solve the dependencies in the script and from now on will use it for all the `crontab` scripts that I will write. Thank you!

Comment: a big pluse one for solving your own `crontab` problem! Good luck.